# In quadrilateral $ABCD$, $\angle BAC=\angle CAD=2\,\angle ACD=40^\circ$ and $\angle ACB=70^\circ$. Find $\angle ADB$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

> Let quadrilateral $ABCD$ satisfy $\angle BAC = \angle CAD = 2\,\angle ACD = 40^\circ$ and $\angle ACB = 70^\circ$. Find $\angle ADB$.

What I tried

1. Ceva’s Theorem (Trigonometry version)
2. Try to construct some equilateral triangle.

Which both failed.

Any hints or solutions please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such upvoting (+6) is exaggerated : the OP hasn't really shown he has worked and hasn't even provided a figure !

Comment: As this question is very easy with the help of some trigonometry, I presume the use of calculator is disallowed?

Comment: Yes , @l1mbo. Calculator isn’t allowed.

Comment: @JeanMarie, actually the OP has shown how he has worked and the figure is not necessary to understand this question. So he deserves more upvoting than six.

Comment: @Angelo, there are some standards. This is just a posted question and the upvotes probably go to the author of the question. Instead of opposing a more experienced community member, if you had already decided to post an answer to a question, you could've at least drawn your own image. No work is shown in the question, whatsoever. A figure is necessary for others to see what progress the OP made. In fact, (at least) in my country, nobody will give you any points on the state exam without a drawing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, Geogebra says it is $\approx 77,34^{\circ}$, so good luck...
[image]

Actually, Ceva might really help:

$${\sin 80\over \sin 40}{\sin(70-x)\over \sin x}{\sin 20\over \sin90} = 1$$

After some manipulation we get $$\cot x = \tan 20+{2\over \cos 10}\implies x =... $$

Comment: Thanks for all downvotes, care to explain why?

Comment: How did you use ceva , like isn't ceva used in a triangle when 3 cevians are given  ?

Comment: Yes, you have $ABC$ and with respect to $D$.

Comment: oh, yes, I see . Thanks! and also +1

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Since $\angle ACB=\angle ABC=70^\circ$, the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles and $\;\overline{AB}=\overline{AC}$.

By applying the law of sines to the triangle $ACD$, we get that:

$\overline{AD}=\overline{AC}\cdot\cfrac{\sin\angle ACD}{\sin\angle ADC}=\overline{AC}\cdot\cfrac{\sin 20^\circ}{\sin 120^\circ}=\cfrac{2\overline{AC}\sin 20^\circ}{\sqrt{3}}\;.$

And, by applying the law of sines to the triangle $ABD$, we get that:

$\overline{AD}\sin\angle ADB=\overline{AB}\sin\angle ABD\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

Let $\;\alpha=\angle ADB\;.$

Since $\;\overline{AD}=\cfrac{2\overline{AC}\sin 20^\circ}{\sqrt{3}}\;$, $\;\overline{AB}=\overline{AC}\;$ and $\;\angle ABD=100^\circ-\alpha\;,\;$ the equality $(*)$ turns into:

$\cfrac{2\overline{AC}\sin 20^\circ\sin\alpha}{\sqrt{3}}=\overline{AC}\sin(100^\circ-\alpha)\;,$

$2\sin 20^\circ\sin\alpha=\sqrt{3}\sin(90^\circ+10^\circ-\alpha)\;,$

$4\sin 10^\circ\cos 10^\circ\sin\alpha=\sqrt{3}\cos(10^\circ-\alpha)\;,$

$4\sin 10^\circ\cos 10^\circ\sin\alpha=\sqrt{3}\left(\cos10^\circ\cos\alpha+\sin 10^\circ\sin\alpha\right)\;,$

$4\sin 10^\circ\sin\alpha=\sqrt{3}\left(\cos\alpha+\tan 10^\circ\sin\alpha\right)\;,$

$\left(4\sin 10^\circ-\sqrt{3}\tan 10^\circ\right)\sin\alpha=\sqrt{3}\cos\alpha\;,$

$\tan\alpha=\cfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4\sin 10^\circ-\sqrt{3}\tan 10^\circ}\;.$

Hence,

$\angle ADB=\alpha=\arctan\left(\cfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4\sin 10^\circ-\sqrt{3}\tan 10^\circ}\right)\simeq\\\simeq 77,3361794^\circ.$

Comment: He he, it is like my picture.

Comment: You are right, I do not have a program to draw, so I have used your drawing. I am sorry.

Comment: If you don't have a program, but want to post an answer, you can take a picture of a real drawing. 

Comment: But I am not good at drawing.